# Add object using ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, rest, angular-ngmodel

I have a form which updates values on submit like this

```
<form ng-submit="updateMovie()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="movie.title"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="movie.rating"/>

    //what to attach here at ng-model//
    <input type="text" ng-modal ="movie.__"/>
   there could be many genre inputs based on how many user wants to input

</form>
```

The object submitted by the form will be of the following type. For the moment lets ***ignore the ids***. I dont know how can I create the genre 
i.e. ***Array of objects***

```
"id": 4792,
"title": "Insidious",
"rating": "7.0",
"genres": [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "horror"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Drama"
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you want the user type any of kind of genre or do you have genres that he can choices?

Comment: look into various multi-select modules available...similar to the way `tags` work on these posts here

Comment: @developer033 , user have to type them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add into a list (`movie.genres`) everything that the user types and click in a button.

So you can have something like this:

```js
angular.module("app", [])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.movie = {};

  $scope.movie.genres = [];
  $scope.add = function() {
    if ($scope.genre) {
      $scope.movie.genres.push($scope.genre);
      $scope.genre = '';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="updateMovie()">
    <label for="title">Title: </label>
    <input type="text" id="title" ng-model="movie.title">
    <br>
    <label for="rating">Rating: </label>
    <input type="text" id="rating" ng-model="movie.rating">
    <br>
    <label for="genre">Genre: </label>
    <input type="text" id="genre" ng-model="genre">
    <button type="button" ng-click="add()">Add genre</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yes that would be appropriate. But any idea how to extend this for multiple genre inputs.
Sorry didn't see the ng-click add in the end

Comment: What do you mean with *multiple* genre inputs?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have an inherent design flaw by trying to allow the user to input ***anything*** and then match that potentially random input to a predefined set of data.  I'd highly recommend an alternative method such as multi-select dropdowns or checkboxes.  Even an auto-suggestion feature that restricted the user to a pre-defined set of genres would be a tremendous improvement.

That said, if you wanted to continue with this approach, you can take steps in the right direction.

Decouple your `ng-model` for the inputted genre(s) from the form data.  This means that in `updateMovie()` you'll transform the data as necessary.

Allow the user to bind genre to a simple string:

```
<input type="text" ng-model ="movie.userGenres"/>
```

In your `updateMovie()` method, delimit the data based on spaces, commas, etc, and map it to your genres array if possible and post that mapped data instead of the user's inputted string.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ngTagInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput).

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('yourCtrl', function() {
    $scope.movie = {
      name: '',
      description: '',
      genre: [],
    };
});


<tags-input id="genre" class="input-border" ng-model="movie.genre"
                            placeholder="Genere for movie"
                            add-on-comma="true"
                            replace-spaces-with-dashes="false"
                            on-tag-added="$tag.text=$tag.text.toLowerCase()"></tags-input>
```

You need to transform genre to your desired format as it is like array of:

```
[{text: 'genre1'}, {text: 'genre2'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use angular ui-select (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)
This can be used to select multiple values.
here are also examples http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/demo-multiple-selection.html

you can also implement your on refresh function which will return the list of available genres + the entered genre
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-choices